# Replacing 'mother and daughter'?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I want to say *they quickly realized we were mother and daughter*. Does it sound natural? I wonder if there are any words which can replace **mother and daughter**. Thank you!

Comment: Are you seeking one word like **siblings** for **bothers and sisters**?

Comment: It is quite natural. Perfectly idiomatic. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we%20were%20mother%20and%20daughter%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Sina- yes, I need a single word like that.

Answer (score -2):

Your sentence is correct. However, there is no fixed term to describe a mother-daughter relationship.

The closest you can get to describing what you wish to convey is using the word **related**.

They quickly realized we were [related](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/related).

Comment: This would apply to any two people within a family. The OP is specifically asking about mother & daughter.

Comment: True. And this is the closest one can get to describing a mother-daughter relationship.

Comment: I suggest that you explicitly mention this in your answer, and perhaps, since you use the word *also*, it's as if you're confirming that the OPs sentence is correct, but you don't actually state that. I think if you address these concerns then your answer may be better received. :)

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer accordingly. Thank you!